# Use OAuth 2.0 with MS Office Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, authentication

Is there a way (either built-in or through a trustworthy add-in) to use OAuth 2.0 for authentication with MS Office Outlook client (on Windows desktop) for Google (or other sites)? Outlook 2016 still seems to only support password auth! The "Outlook Mail & Calendar" (also known just as "Mail") app on Win10 supports OAuth for at least Google and Yahoo accounts, but that app is missing functionality (found in "real" Outlook) that I need.

Everything I've found online talks about creating a client that uses OAuth to access *Outlook.com*, Microsoft's current webmail offering, but this is the reverse of what I'm trying to do; I want to use the client I have (Outlook, the desktop Win32 app that is part of MS Office) to connect to arbitrary (email, typically IMAP+SMTP) services that use OAuth for authentication.

While this question is about a security feature, it's not really a security question; I'm just trying to use a feature that every other non-trivial desktop (or mobile) email client supports, most of them for years now. It seems impossible that Outlook doesn't support it at all, but I can't find a way to use it!

Comment: [Related](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ivfranji/authentication-enabling-modern-auth-oauth2/).  The problem you will run into is that Google only supports the OAUTH 2.0 standard itself, and i suspect, the version Microsoft supports is sliently modified.

Comment: [Has recently has of Nov 2015](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/RdAVxF_GTsc) Outlook 2016 did not support what you want to do though.  *You are out of luck*

Comment: With G Suite's [planned shutdown](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/12/less-secure-apps-oauth-google-username-password-incorrect.html) of less secure apps, I think it's time to revisit this thread. [This link](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/gmailoauth.htm) states "Outlook for Office 365, Outlook 2019 or Outlook 2016 (except for the Volume License msi-version) offer native support for OAuth 2.0". Why should Volume License matter? My colleague installed Office through a file called Setup.X64.he-il_O365ProPlusRetail_[random]_TX_PR_b_64_.exe and Outlook (1902) still wanted a password.